# Cloudformation build stuck at "create in progress" - trying to add it to use specific SG

Tags: aws-cloudformation

So the last item I added to this template was the attempt to have it use a particular SecurityGroup. I did not want it to create a new one. When I do the validate check that comes back ok but apparently my code is still not correct. Other that the template was working ok.

I have tried all I can think of. there is no error when i finally times out other than "internal error" so I am at a loss here.

```
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Description: Testing using this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-02765
  SecGroup:
     Description: Name of security group
     Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 key pair for SSH access to the EC2 instance.
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type.
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
...
...
...
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      SubnetId: subnet-08b
      KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecGroup
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - HVM64
'''

all I am trying to do is use the items I listed in the template. the vpc,securitygroup. The last time this worked was when I had the code in the template that builds a new SG. I than changed my mind and want to use an existing SG. so somewhere I messed up
```

Comment: So I do know that it is for sure my  assignment of the security group. I commented all the items refering to the security group and the template completed to completion using the 'default SG, unfortunately it is not the default SG I want to use.

Comment: Try using AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup without ::GroupName. (looking at a template of my own right now).

Comment: I have tried w/o ::GroupName, but I get the error:     type AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup for parameter name SecurityGroup does not exist.

Comment: Ah, I just looked more closely and I have: SecurityGroupIds as Property and then !Ref MySecGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in my templates:

```
Parameters:
  SecGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
...
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Properties:
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref SecGroup
```

Comment: wow.. that is intersting. when I run it I get: Parameter validation failed: parameter type AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup for parameter name SecurityGroup does not exist. Rollback requested by user.

Comment: I think the copy-paste messed something up and when I manually did the SE formatting I made it worse. See the changes.

Comment: so weird.. that is what I have and it error with the error previously posted. I am reposting my code..maybe you can see if I am messing up..

Comment: Stupid question: is the SG you are trying to use actually in the VPC you're working in?

Comment: That is not a stupid question for me.. haha.. yes I confirmed. I only have one VPC

Comment: Parameters:
  VPC:
    Description: Testing using    VPC 
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-0c99537
  SecGroup:
     Description: Name of security group
     Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 key pair for SSH access to the EC2 instance.
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type.

Comment: `code` Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      SubnetId: subnet-08b80a3df1970e4c4
      KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecGroup
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - HVM64

Comment: not sure how you did the code in comments. I thought it was `code`

Comment: Try using `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id` as parameter type